# Jquery do something every few seconds unless all values in object are true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var obj = { 
    eins : false,
  zwei : false,
  drei : false
}; 

$.each(obj, function (k, v) {
  if (!v) {
    console.log(false);
  }
});
```

Now what I am trying to do is the following: Check if all of the values in the obj are true. If they are do this, if they are not, try again.

I tried messing with setInterval and $.each but couldn't manage to make it run synchronously..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple loop to see if the object is all true and an if/else to determine the step is all that is needed.

```js
var obj = { 
    eins : false,
    zwei : false,
    drei : false
}; 

//function to call to see if code is updated
function check () {

  //Check to see that every property in the object is true
  var isValid = Object.keys(obj).every( function (key) {
    return obj[key];
  });
  
  //if true, do what you need to do
  if(isValid) {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";  
  } else {  //not true, than run check again
      window.setTimeout(check, 500); //next check is half a second 
  }
  
}

check();  //initialize the checking

//A way to flip the data for the demo
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    obj = { 
        eins : true,
        zwei : true,
        drei : true
    };
});
```

```html
<button>Set</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array.prototype.every` method:

```
var allTrue = Object.keys(obj).every(function(key) {
   return obj[key] === true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use $.each() at all. for(... in ...) works great inside a function called at a predefined interval.

```
var obj = {
    eins: false,
    zwei: false,
    drei: false,
};

var id = setInterval(function() {
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj[key] === false) return;
    }
    // No property was false
    clearInterval(id);
    // do anything you want here
}, 1000);
```

If you need to retrieve a value after the check, look at Promise class :)

Answer (score 0):

Just created a simple demo of what you were trying..

```js
var obj = {
  eins: false,
  zwei: false,
  drei: false
};

var doStuffTimer = setInterval(function() {
    $.each(obj, function(k, v) {
      if (!v) {
        $('#logger').append('<p>obj.eins = ' + obj.eins + ' obj.zwei = ' + obj.zwei + ' obj.drei = ' + obj.drei + '</p>');
      }
    });
    $('#logger').append("<p>--------------</p>");
  }, 3000), //check every 3 seconds
    
  flagTimer = setInterval(function() { /* below timer is for demo purpose only */
    if (!obj.eins) {
      obj.eins = true;
    } else if (!obj.zwei) {
      obj.zwei = true;
    } else if (!obj.drei) {
      obj.drei = true;
    } else {
      $('#logger').append('<p>Final Result:  obj.eins = ' + obj.eins + ' obj.zwei = ' + obj.zwei + ' obj.drei = ' + obj.drei + '</p>');
      clearInterval(flagTimer);
      clearInterval(doStuffTimer); //clear the doStuffTimer; we dont want to keep the timer running
    }
  }, 5000); //change the flag every 5 seconds.. just for demo purpose
```

```css
p {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logger"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach :

```js
var obj = { 
    eins : false,
  zwei : false,
  drei : false
};

function allTrue (obj){
  var all_true = true;
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    if(obj[key] === false) all_true = false;
  });
  return all_true;
}

function doSomething (){
  // Do something
  var key_;
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    if(obj[key] === false){
      key_ = key;
    }
  });
  obj[key_] = true;
  console.log('iteration');
  if(!allTrue(obj)) doSomething();
}

doSomething();
```